El CMD No reconoce ningun Comando!
Estudiante recien.
Necesito la colaboración de ustedes compañeros.
Mi CMD no ejecuta los comandos, la verdad no se que sera,
pero por error borre EL PATH original, ahora no me deja agregar lo que tenia adentro claramente no se que debo pasar al path, porque no me deja agregar normalmente dentro del PATH.
Le doy editar y no abre ventana, solo nueva Variable y ya.
entonces como soluciono esto, lo necesito para ejecutar y seguir en mis pequeños ejercicios y proyectos.
les agradezco la ayuda.
